# How to use ST_GeomFromText with PG::prepare? (Ruby)

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, pg

I am having trouble with the syntax relate to `PG::prepare`, `ST_GeomFromText`, and `POINT`.

This works:

```
sql = %Q%insert into #{table_name} (latlong, place_name) values (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 4326), $1 )%

conn.prepare('statement1', sql)
```

This does **not** work:

```
sql = %Q%insert into #{table_name} (latlong, place_name) values (ST_GeomFromText('POINT($1 $2)', 4326), $3 )%

conn.prepare('statement1', sql)
```

Error:

```
in `prepare': ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1 (PG::IndeterminateDatatype)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of this:**

```
sql = %Q%insert into #{table_name} (latlong, place_name) values (ST_GeomFromText('POINT($1 $2)', 4326), $3 )%
conn.prepare('statement1', sql)
```

**Try this:**

```
sql = %Q%insert into #{table_name} (latlong, place_name) values (ST_GeomFromText($1, 4326))%
conn.prepare('statement1', sql)
```

The `POINT(long lat)` string is represented as a single value, `$1` in this example.

```
CONN.exec_prepared( 'statement1', [ "POINT(long lat)", foobar ]
```

The whole issue occurs when PostGIS tries to parse your above statement, it tries to create a geometry with `$1 $2` which simply doesn't work and gives you the error you are are now familiar with. Instead pass the WKT (well known text) `POINT(long lat)` in as a single value after your statement is prepared.